# AppCache stucks on android native browser

Tags: android-browser, html5-appcache

I run into a strange issue with my mobile site on which i'm trying to implement the appcache functionality. It works fine on desktop (Chrome & Firefox), on chrome for android and on iOS. But the android native browser (Android 4.3 running on a Samsung Galaxy S3) is driving me crazy.

The appcache is working fine, as long as i'm waiting till the browser downloaded all files who are defined in the manifest file. But if i click on a link, while the browser's still downloading, the download process stops and can't be "reactivated". Even when i refresh the browser or update the manifest file, nothing happens. To start over, i need to clear browser cache, close the tab, close the browser app and restart it again.

For debugging on the mobile device, i'm using this script: http://jonathanstark.com/blog/debugging-html-5-offline-application-cache and check the log in the debug mode. This is the status i got, as soon the download process crashes: **"online: yes, event: downloading, status: downloading"**

I'm serving the manisfest.appcache file as a cache-manifest and set the cache-control header in .htaccess like this:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
<Files *.appcache>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age: 0"
</Files>
```

And this is how the content of my manifest.appcache file looks like

```
CACHE MANIFEST

/some/nice/urls
/another/url
/even/more/urls

NETWORK:
*
http://*
```

In total, the user needs to download around 10MB.

Did someone run into the same or a similar issue with the android native browser?

Thanks for any advices!

Cheers