# Cache Manifest Update Hangs On 'ondownloading' Event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

I have an offline application that uses HTML5 application cache. For the most part it is working great. I have a few clients that access the app on multiple devices (Desktop,IOS, Android, etc.)

The initial problem was that any time the client's web server is restarted for maintenance or any other purpose the application stopped working on some devices. They just received a run time server error. We were able to fix this by pragmatically updating the cache manifest file on start up when the server is restarted. We never figured out why restarting the server required a cache update on some devices but it worked so we put it on the back burner to research later.

Now we have a new issue. Some Android devices when the server is restarted, will not update the cache. If the cache manifest is updated manually without restarting the server, the cache updates fine but if the server restarts the Androids work as expected during the 'checking listener' and the 'downloading listener' but it never moves onto the 'progress listener'. It does not fall into the error 'error listener' it just completes the ondownloading function then stops.

Here's my code:
all of the below code is in an external js file and the registerCacheMethod is called in the head of the master page of an aspx project.

```
    var updatePhase = 'none';
    var cacheCount = -1;


    function handleCacheUpdated()
    {
        updatePhase = 'handleCacheUpdated()';
        $('#modal_body_progress').html('Cache Updated Successfully');

        alert('The application was updated. Login required.');

        window.location.href = 'Login.aspx';
    }


function handleOnDownloading()
{

          updatePhase = 'Downloading';

          $('#modal_body_Header').html('Cache Update');

          $('#modal_body_text').html('Please do not close the browser or navigate away from this page while updating.');


          $('#modal_body_progress').html('Updating...');

          $('#modal_popup_container').css('display','inline');

          cacheCount = 0;

     return false;
}
function handleOnProgress()
{
    updatePhase = 'Progress';
    cacheCount++;
    $('#modal_body_progress').html('Updating Entry: ' + cacheCount);
    return false;
}
function handleCacheError(e)
{
    $('#modal_body_progress').html('Error Loading Entry: (Count: ' + cacheCount + ', Phase: ' + updatePhase + ')');


    return false;
}

    function handleNoUpdate()
    {
        updatePhase = 'No Update';
    }
    function handleChecking()
    {
        updatePhase = 'Checking';
    }
    function handleCacheObsolete()
    {
        updatePhase = 'CacheObsolete';
    }

 function registerCacheMethods(method)
    {

        try
        {
            var cache = window.applicationCache;
            if (cache == undefined) 
            {
                alert('This browser does not support Application Cache');
                return false;
            }
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            /*
            * Between the poll and registering of the event you might miss the CACHEREADY event. This block will handle this.
            */
            if (cache.status === applicationCache.UPDATEREADY)
            {
                handleCacheUpdated();
                return false;
            }
            cache.addEventListener('updateready', handleCacheUpdated, false);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            cache.addEventListener('cached', handleCacheUpdated, false);
            cache.addEventListener('noupdate', handleNoUpdate, false);
            cache.addEventListener('downloading', handleOnDownloading, false);
            cache.addEventListener('progress', handleOnProgress, false);
            cache.addEventListener('error', handleCacheError, false);
            cache.addEventListener('obsolete', handleCacheObsolete, false);
            cache.addEventListener('checking', handleChecking, false);
        }
        catch (EX)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

***EDIT***

I managed to find out some more information on this. Number one I found the device and browser that has the problem. The issue happens on Android 4.3 running on a Samsung Galaxy S3. With this new information I found that someone already asked a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21996791/appcache-stucks-on-android-native-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an IIS (or web server you use) configuration problem here. First when you ignore the first restart problem, you basically open a new door to get new errors, probably that's why acting different up to each browser type. i advice you to focus Restart problem it was there in first place. and if i am not wrong just be sure your web server or (client's own web servers) must be configured to set expires headers for *.appcache files to expire immediately. & you should never access to cache files manually. for apache this directive works.

`ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"`